# Converting a XML Object into JSON from OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have created a basic ASP.Net Web Application and I am trying to use the OpenWeatherMap API with this. (first time dealing with APIs).

The Info I have about the WebAPI is:

*You can search weather forecast for 5 days with data every 3 hours by city name. All weather data can be obtained in JSON and XML formats.
There is a possibility to receive a central district of the city/town with its own parameters (geographic coordinates/id/name) in API response. Example
API call:
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}
Parameters:
q city name and country code divided by comma, use ISO 3166 country codes
Examples of API calls:*

**api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml**

Currently I have this working when I use the api that returns a json object

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric

However if I simply change the URL to the first (which returns the XML) my application no longer retrieves the data from the API.

I have tried amended the mode=xml into mode=json but still no avail.

How can I use the first web API?

Many thanks

--Edit:

In my model class i have the following method:

```
string url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/…;
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(url); 
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content); 

return jsonContent;
```

(taken out the key) I then call this method from my view. However I cannot use that api call that has the =xml at the end

Comment: What code are you using to get this data?

Comment: I am using C#. Edited main comment to show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is when result is returned as xml, you are using a `JavaScriptSerializer` to Deserialize it.
xml is not json, hence the `Deserialization` would have failed

what you need is a `XmlSerializer` to deserializae the result

below is some code to get you started:

```
string url = @"http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1&mode=xml";
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(url);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(weatherdata));
weatherdata result = null;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(content))
{
     result = (weatherdata)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

notice that typeof `weatherdata` - it is no point of Deserialize into non strong type object if you are going to deserialize into object,
there is noting you can do with it.

if you don't want to hand code the strong type model, copy the xml result into clipboard then use VS (not sure other version but 2017 as example) toolbar 
`Edit -> paste special -> Paste xml as classes` to generate the strong type class for you